# Chat non-functional, spam fiddly technical details

Tags: bug, flagging

@NiallC. asked why I hadn't flagged a spammy post as spam, but since he locked and deleted it, I couldn't answer him.

[Debris from Roof causing Gutters to clog](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/66402/debris-from-roof-causing-gutters-to-clog)

As I was about to flag it spam, I see a highlighted section at the end of the flag instructions that mutters about "without disclosing the users relationship to the site" - well, this spammer was not shy about that, so if that's a requirement, the spam flag is telling me not to flag as spam, or it needs some rewriting.

So I flagged as not an answer, and commented about its rich, meaty, canned nature.

In trying to figure out a way to tell Niall what he first asked and then removed my ability to answer, I tried to go to chat. From here, logged in here. chat tells me I need to log in first. But I was. I try to log in to chat "directly" and it logs me into the SE main site. Go to chat from there, it wants me to log in. Endless loop, no worky.

So here I am blathering on Meta. I understand the logic behind not having PMs, due to all the crap PMs can lead to, but it sure is the long way around Robin Hood's Barn.

Comment: @NiallC. your answer is here, since I can't answer there.

Comment: For the benefit of people that can't see it, my comment was: _"If you think it's spam, why wouldn't you flag it as such?"_. I thought the question was rhetorical, and didn't expect a discussion to ensue. I'll write an answer later when I have time.